# How to Create a Virtual Network Adapter in .NET?

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, network-programming, vpn

I would like to create/add a virtual network adapter to a client operating system at runtime (via code), preferably in C#. Something similar to that of what VirtualBox/VMware/Himachi creates when you install their software. I am guessing this will require some C/C++ shenanigans for the driver integration, but if it is doable with only C#, all the better.

I am aware of OpenVPN, their stuff is primarily in C, and I am also aware of the TUN/TAP drivers floating around, I just didn't know if these were the only solutions not requiring me creating a fully loaded network driver for Windows.

Comment: I'm curious to know if it is possible to do **any** low-level Windows drivers like this in managed .NET code. I don't think I've ever heard of anything like this being done, though I may be wrong.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you need simple funcionality then you can use Microsoft Loopback Adapter. To install it use devcon tool. Here is some info about it http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311272. 
**devcon -r install %WINDIR%\Inf\Netloop.inf *MSLOOP** After that you can use WMI query with C# to obtain new connection name and then netsh to configure it (ie. netsh int ip set address name="Local Area Connection 2" static 192.168.0.3 255.0.0.0)

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. I am familiar with creating/utilizing MS Loopbacks, but didn't know about devcon's existence. Excellent answer, have yet to find another as logical in my searches. Thanks alot!

Comment: For those on Win7 x64, you may be interested in http://superuser.com/questions/305685/devcon-exe-not-working-in-windows7-x64

Comment: MD5 of the x64 version: 3904d0698962e09da946046020cbcb17

Comment: `devcon failed` for me.