# Virtual Network Adapter Driver with API preferably with c# api

Tags: c#, .net, api, components, driver

I am in need of a virtual network adapter driver for Windows XP SP2+ that has an API, preferably one that supports c#.  I need to be able to access the bytes that have been sent over the interface and send bytes over it myself.  The general idea of what I am looking for is similar to virtual serial ports like this one http://www.fabulatech.com/virtual-serial-port-control.html but for Ethernet instead of serial.

I am looking for a commercial grade product and would love to hear of any you have seen or tried.

Comment: Check this question on SO. Might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2234102/how-to-create-a-virtual-network-adapter-in-net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I realize it's not quite the answer you're looking for, there is [winpcap](http://www.winpcap.org/install/default.htm), which allows you to capture and transmit packets over an actual network interface. There are bindings available for [C#](http://www.winpcap.org/misc/links.htm), which makes it useful for your purposes.

You can make use of the [loopback interface](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/839013) device, which will allow you to have a local only interface to make use of.

Comment: this is an idea i can try, still would love to hear of a commercial package if anyone knows of one.

Comment: winpcap is what you would use to get all the packets that traverse an interface.. but if you are looking for "virtual serial port, but for ethernet", then just open a socket and push out your data.

Comment: @boo i don't want a socket, i want a virtual interface.  The idea being I want to allow people to pretend they are using a network interface but in reality I will be intercepting their packets and doing something else with them.  It is the same thing VPN software does.

Comment: also, Petesh is right, you could mock together something that would work using winpcap and a loopback adapter but it would be a lot more work and more prone to errors which is why I don't want to use it. The problem is that with this method I would have to monitor and capture packets, what I want to do is have the software only driver capture and queue up packets sent to it. Then let me query it to get them out of its buffer.