# Socket.Bind and Connect using local addresses

Tags: c#, sockets

To test my server/client application, where each client is known by its IP address, I created several network adapters (see [How to Create a Virtual Network Adapter in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2234102/how-to-create-a-virtual-network-adapter-in-net)). Both 192.168.0.10 and 11 now correspond to local ethernet adaptors (10 being the "real" one, 11 being a loopback adapter).

The client can `Connect` itself to the server as long as it doesn't `Bind` its socket to a specific address. But if it does, the server doesn't notice anything and a timeout occurs in the client (I want to use `Bind` as for security reasons the server automatically detects which client is connecting itself by looking at the IP address of the remote end point of the new connection: the server will drop the connection at once if it doesn't know the IP address - previously I was using several virtual machines, but it uses a lot more RAM and is less practical to use).

Here's the code in my server, listening eg on 192.168.0.10:1234

```
IPEndPoint myEP = new IPEndPoint(myAddress, myPort);
Socket listeningSocket = new Socket(myAddress.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
listeningSocket.Bind(myEP);
listeningSocket.Listen(50);
Socket acceptedSocket = listeningSocket.Accept();
```

Here's the code in my client, binding eg to 192.168.0.11 (any port) and connecting to 192.168.0.10:1234

```
Socket socket = new Socket(svrAddress.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(myAddress, 0)); // Bind to local address using automatic port
socket.Connect(new IPEndPoint(svrAddress, svrPort)); // Works fine without Bind, timeout with Bind
```

I've tried the same using the corresponding IPv6 addresses but I get the exact same result.
If I `Bind` the client on the same address (using a different port than the server), it works fine.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT Here is my test projects (it might be useful to someone)

Server part:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Server
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IPAddress[] ips = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList;

            string line = string.Empty;
            while (line != "q")
            {
                // Gets the IP address to listen on.
                Console.WriteLine("IP to listen on:");
                int count = 0;
                foreach (IPAddress ip in ips)
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", ++count, ip.ToString());

                string numString = Console.ReadLine();
                int pos = Convert.ToInt32(numString) - 1;
                IPAddress myAddress = ips[pos]; // Removing or not the scope ID doesn't change anything as "localEndPoint" below will contain it no matter what

                // Binds and starts listening.
                IPEndPoint myEP = new IPEndPoint(myAddress, 12345);
                Socket listeningSocket = new Socket(myAddress.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                listeningSocket.Bind(myEP);
                listeningSocket.Listen(50);

                IPEndPoint localEndPoint = (IPEndPoint)listeningSocket.LocalEndPoint;
                Console.WriteLine("Listening on {0}:{1}", localEndPoint.Address, localEndPoint.Port);

                Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            // Accepts new connections and sends some dummy byte array, then closes the socket.
                            Socket acceptedSocket = listeningSocket.Accept();
                            IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint = (IPEndPoint)acceptedSocket.RemoteEndPoint;
                            Console.WriteLine("Accepted connection from {0}:{1}.", remoteEndPoint.Address, remoteEndPoint.Port);
                            acceptedSocket.Send(new byte[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 });
                            acceptedSocket.Close(5000);
                            Console.WriteLine("-= FINISHED =- Type q to quit, anything else to continue");
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        { }
                    });

                line = Console.ReadLine();

                // Closes the listening socket.
                listeningSocket.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Client part

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Client
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IPAddress[] ips = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList;

            string line = string.Empty;
            while (line != "q")
            {
                // Gets the IP address to connect to (removes the "scope ID" if it's an IPv6).
                Console.WriteLine("IP to connect to:");
                int count = 0;
                foreach (IPAddress ip in ips)
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", ++count, ip.ToString());

                string numString = Console.ReadLine();
                int pos = Convert.ToInt32(numString) - 1;
                IPAddress svrAddress = ips[pos].AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6
                    ? new IPAddress(ips[pos].GetAddressBytes())
                    : ips[pos];

                Console.WriteLine("Connecting to " + svrAddress);

                // Gets the IP address to bind on (can chose "none" - also removes the "scope ID" if it's an IPv6).
                Console.WriteLine("IP to bind to:");
                Console.WriteLine("0: none");
                count = 0;
                IPAddress[] filteredIps = ips.Where(i => i.AddressFamily == svrAddress.AddressFamily).ToArray();
                foreach (IPAddress ip in filteredIps)
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", ++count, ip.ToString());

                numString = Console.ReadLine();
                pos = Convert.ToInt32(numString) - 1;
                IPEndPoint localEndPoint = (pos == -1)
                    ? null
                    : new IPEndPoint(
                        filteredIps[pos].AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6
                            ? new IPAddress(filteredIps[pos].GetAddressBytes())
                            : filteredIps[pos]
                        , 0);
                Console.WriteLine("Binding to " + (localEndPoint == null ? "none" : localEndPoint.Address.ToString()));

                // Binds to an address if we chose to.
                Socket socket = new Socket(svrAddress.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                if (localEndPoint != null)
                    socket.Bind(localEndPoint);

                Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        // Connects to the server and receives the dummy byte array, then closes the socket.
                        socket.Connect(new IPEndPoint(svrAddress, 12345));
                        IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint = (IPEndPoint)socket.RemoteEndPoint;
                        Console.WriteLine("Connected to {0}:{1}", remoteEndPoint.Address, remoteEndPoint.Port);
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[10];
                        Console.WriteLine((socket.Receive(buffer) == buffer.Length) ? "Received message" : "Incorrect message");
                        socket.Close();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        // An exception occured: should be a SocketException due to a timeout if we chose to bind to an address.
                        Console.WriteLine("ERROR: " + ex.ToString());
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("-= FINISHED =- Type q to quit, anything else to continue");
                });

                line = Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to present the smallest possible example code that exhibits your problem.  Most users here won't want to debug your long code.

Comment: @japreiss I first added a small sample (5 lines for server, 3 for client), then later on I also added the full source of a simple test project for both (I thought it might help someone as it's working fine, but maybe it also scares people who'd want to answer).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually it was a configuration issue with my network adapters and it has to do with "**Weak and Strong Host model**".

From what I've read ( [Using a specific network interface for a socket in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065495/using-a-specific-network-interface-for-a-socket-in-windows) ) binding on Windows previous to Vista would only work for incoming traffic, and it wouldn't do anything for outgoing traffic.

Starting with Vista it's possible but by default it won't work: you need to allow the "weak host model" using

```
netsh interface ipv4 set interface "loopback" weakhostreceive=enabled
netsh interface ipv4 set interface "loopback" weakhostsend=enabled
```

See https://web.archive.org/web/20150402200610/http://blog.loadbalancer.org/direct-server-return-on-windows-2008-using-loopback-adpter/ for more info.

EDIT

Actually, instead of creating several loopback adapters and changing their host model, it's a lot better and easier to just create one loopback adapter, give it several IP addresses on a different network than your real IP, and then only use those IPs for your test. That way there's no routing issue, and you're sure everything stays local (as there's no routing between the real and loopback adapter).

Answer (score 6):

Use below code in the server for binding the connection on all the interface on the same port.

```
// Binds and starts listening.
IPEndPoint myEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 12345);
```