# Creating a TCPClient and binding to a IPAddress created with extern AddIPAddress

Tags: c#, tcp, tcpclient

The problem I am having when I create IP addresses on my network adapter with:

```
 [DllImport("iphlpapi.dll", SetLastError = true)]
 private static extern UInt32 AddIPAddress(UInt32 address, UInt32 ipMask, int ifIndex, out IntPtr nteContext, out IntPtr nteInstance);

 public void AddIpAddressToInterface(string ipAddress, string subnetMask)
    {
        var ipAdd = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(ipAddress);
        var subNet = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(subnetMask);

        var nteContext = 0;
        var nteInstance = 0;
        IntPtr ptrNteContext;
        var ptrNteInstance = new IntPtr(nteInstance);
        UInt32 result = AddIPAddress((uint)BitConverter.ToInt32(ipAdd.GetAddressBytes(), 0), (uint)BitConverter.ToInt32(subNet.GetAddressBytes(), 0), _adapterIndex, out ptrNteContext,
                            out ptrNteInstance);

        string errorFmt = "Cannot create IP address {0} for adapter {1}. Error: {2}";

        if (result == (UInt32)WINERRORS.ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            _ipaddressList.Add(ipAddress, ptrNteContext);
        }
        else if (result == (UInt32)WINERRORS.ERROR_OBJECT_ALREADY_EXISTS)
        {
            Logger.LogWarning(string.Format(errorFmt, ipAddress, subNet, (WINERRORS)result));
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                Logger.LogError(string.Format(errorFmt, ipAddress, subNet, (WINERRORS)result));
            }
            catch
            {
                Logger.LogError(string.Format(errorFmt, ipAddress, subNet, result));
            }
        }
    }
```

I attempt to bind to the IP using: Note: LocalPort is 0. LocalAddress is the one created with AddIpAddressToInterface ex. 10.43.55.XXX

```
 var localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(LocalAddress, LocalPort);
 _client = new TcpClient(localEndPoint);
```

but I get this error:

```
The requested address is not valid in its context
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress      SocketAddress)
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP)
at System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient..ctor(IPEndPoint localEP)
at CPCToolbox.Shared.TCPConnectionHandler.InitializeNewTCP()
```

I can do a ipconfig /all and see my IP addresses. the static one is is 10.43.99.199.

[image: ipconfig]

Routes:

[image: IP Routes]

The connect call host is a remote host is 10.43.99.50 port 18000 on subnet 255.255.240.0

```
 _client.Connect(_Host, _Port);
```

Comment: I personally would not post my ip address on line but anyways .. take a look at this posting it may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11290323/socket-bind-and-connect-using-local-addresses

Comment: These addresses are on a isolated test network.... Thanks I will look into this.

Comment: also copy your route entries..

Comment: No dice DJ went to a socket object instead of a TCPClient set the loopback and still getting "AddressNotAvailable: The requested address is not valid in its context"

Comment: @dvasanth I added the routes.